# Use of type modifiers(near,far,huge) with normal variables

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, turbo-c

I used type modifiers(far,near,huge) **with normal variables** rather than pointers and found that these pointer type modifiers are only applicable for the global normal variable but an error is generated when used with a variable local to a block.

```
int near a,far b,huge c;

int main()
{
 int d,e,f;

// int near a,far b,,huge c;
// long int near a,far b,huge c;
// long long int near a,far b,huge c;

//printf("\n size of a=%d ,b=%d ,c=%d ,d=%d ,e=%d ,f=%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(b),sizeof(c),sizeof(d),sizeof(e),sizeof(f));

printf("\n address of a=%u ,b=%u ,c=%u ,d=%u ,e=%u,f=%u",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);
  return 0;
  }
```

why is this allowed with a global variable and not with a local variable. Additionally, what does the variable finally becomes i.e. it becomes a pointer,an integer with greater range or entirely something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is placed on the stack can't be far modified.

You can place "**non-far** variables" in the stack, but not "**far** variables".

You can place "**non-far** pointers to **non-far** data" in the stack, but not "**far** pointers to **non-far** data**".

You can place "**non-far** pointers to **far** data" in the stack, but not "**far** pointers to **far** data".

Try this:

```
far int       var        = 0; /* OK */
far int far* far_var_ptr = &var; /* OK: far pointer to far data*/ 
int far*     var_ptr     = &var; /* OK: non-far pointer to far data*/ */

int main()
{
int far*      var_ptr2    = &var; /* OK: Non-far ptr to far data */
far int far* far_var_ptr2 = &var; /* Fail: far ptr to far data */ 
far int       var2         = 0;     /* Fail: far data */
}
```

The key is that you can't define far data on the stack. Variables on the stack are:

Placed within a defined range of memory

Its exact location depends on the call stack before: it can't be known at compile time

This is not a far data:

```
int far* var;
```

It is an non-modified pointer to far data. The pointer itself is just a number not far modified that points to data in a far segment (platform specific).

This is far data:

```
far int* var;
```

And this too:

```
far int far* var;
```

**The storage (far, near, huge) modifier of a variable (or function) is placed before the variable type.**

Answer (score 2):

`near`, `far`, and `huge` affect where, and in what type of memory, a variable is stored. Since local variables are always stored on the stack, using these modifiers on local variables doesn't make any sense.

Note that these features are all unique to the 16-bit DOS platform. They are not used on modern systems -- you can safely ignore them.

Comment: i understand that these can be ignored but this was done purely for research purpose(writing TSRs in 16-bit DOS :D) I could not even find anything in the gcc documentations.

Comment: Also, these type modifiers were used to access the data within the data or code segment by increasing the size of the pointer variable.

Comment: @NeoR there was never a version of GCC for real mode DOS .  The DJGPP project runs in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: @M.M thanks did not know that also the code is actually written in 16-bit Turbo-C but it's hard to find manuals of Turbo-C these days though I did manage to get my hands on the digital copy of official IBM Turbo-c manual still could not reach to any conclusions.

Comment: I was having a (very loosely formed) idea regarding automatic garbage collectors and since local variables is usually based on an EBP offset - I thought it might be useful to get the data-segment / far address instead.. and well, do some sneaky shit with some kind of doubly linked lists to the actual heap-allocated objects - for like.. easy out-of-scope checks against current stack frame. I guess that's a bust... :/